# How to dynamically set the schema argument of an entity?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

There is an entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITMMASTER" , schema = "TOMCTB")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ITMREF_0")
    private String code_article;

    @Column(name = "ACCCOD_0")
    private String acccod;

    ...

}
```

My application will run in different schemas , so how to set dynamically the value of the `schema` argument ?

Comment: Do you mean that the schema name will differ depending on the target DB/environment or there are several `Article` entities in different schemas of same DB?

Comment: Do you use hibernate? if so, the trick may be done with its configuration file.

Comment: I use `JPQL` ; the schema name will differ depending on the environment ; for example environment test , prod.

Comment: If there is just one schema for all entities and its name depends on target environment, this can be solved by 1) removing `schema` from `@Table` definition; 2) setting the property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema` in `application.properties` (or .yml) depending on target environment. But I'm in doubt about the approach. Shema names shouldn't vary with test|prod. Like package names, do they depend on target environments?

Comment: in SQL Server there is notion of schema ; and the environments are the schemas defined in SQL Server.